# How to reshape an array of lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have the following array:

```
 array([ list(['4.224609607748e+00', '4.085857782359e+00', '1.273383604708e+00', '-6.802974691818e-03']),
   list(['9.099528133406e-03', '6.867550219273e-03', '5.859231188647e-03', '3.684441849425e-03']),
   list(['5.836775773317e-04', '-2.316776085880e-16', '-1.456850991492e-16', '-2.307897076406e-17']),
   list(['4.140895678156e-03', '2.603906355541e-03', '4.125025757803e-04', '-1.739011495381e-03']),
   list(['-1.681896173898e-03', '-5.241735641835e-04', '-1.739011375813e-03', '-1.681896058258e-03']), dtype=object)
```

I would like to modify it such that it is no longer an array of 6 lists, but an array of shape (6,4) (i.e., each floating point number is an element in the array). I would also like to change dtype to float (which I am unable to do not because it will not recognize the lists as floats).

Is there a way that I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: But the last row has only one string?

Comment: This is not possible. Your list is a ragged array.

Comment: Even if I remove the last row?

Comment: `numpy` automatically converts non-ragged lists to a an `ndarray`. If you want `float`s then just change the `dtype=np.float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need:

```
a = np.asarray([list(map(float, item)) for item in a])
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. The shape is still the same.

Comment: How come? I test it after removing the last row, and the final shape is exactly (5,3).